# Form input to display on next page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to get whatever the user put in the input box and use it on the next page, so I can then use javascript with the entered value but I have no idea how. I've seen a lot of people say use php and server side scripting but I don't know how to set that up. I know the php language.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="GET" action="level5.html">
Troops: <input type="text" name="troops" value="0">
<input type="submit" value="send">
</body>
</html>
```

Then on the next page I'm trying to get "You chose 500 troops", then make the 500 a javascript variable.

Comment: set a session for whatever they typed into the box.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you want to use php, did you setup wamp/xampp (for windows) or mamp ( for mac )?

Comment: You can try Cookies :http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_cookies.htm

Comment: Just use $a=$_GET['troops']; in level5.html(change it to level5.php)

Comment: [**Sessions**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) being a server-side method, is indeed the way to go, especially when it comes to passing a variable into JS.

Comment: I haven't tried wamp/xampp yet. The session doesn't seem to be working. I've tried cookies but had no luck. Professor could you elaborate a bit more I'm a bit confused on what you think I should do.

Comment: What do you mean the session isn't working? Show us what you tried. @user3491814

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a script that reads in the url parameters ([source](http://www.tutorials.de/javascript-ajax/149174-probleme-mit-dem-auslesen-von-variablen.html#post768441)):

```
HTTP_GET_VARS = [];

strGET = document.location.search.substr(1, document.location.search.length);

if (strGET !== '') {
  gArr = strGET.split('&');
  for (i = 0; i < gArr.length; ++i) {
    v = '';
    vArr = gArr[i].split('=');
    if (vArr.length > 1) {
      v = vArr[1];
    }
    HTTP_GET_VARS[unescape(vArr[0])] = unescape(v);
  }
}

function GET(v) {
  if (!HTTP_GET_VARS[v]) {
    return 'undefined';
  }
  return HTTP_GET_VARS[v];
}
```

**HTML**

I put both ends in the same file. This reloads the page with the paramters set. Obviously you could do that without needing to reload if you stay on the same page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form method="GET" action="index.html">
      Troops: <input type="text" name="troops" value="0">
      <input type="submit" value="send">
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.writeln ('Troops: ' + GET('troops'));
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NRpXKn3OKYC1gQAXNsOo?p=preview) to try it out.

EDIT: I changed the plnkr to have the exact same structure as your question with two separate files.

---

Since you want to use the value on several other pages the simple approach above might prove too limited. As you would have to send all the data again to the following page.
Although this is absolutely doable, one of the other suggested approaches might be more elegant.

**DOM Storage**

If you use a fairly modern browser (IE8+, FF3.5+, C4+) you can utilize [DOM storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Storage).

`window.sessionStorage.setItem(field, value)` to save a value
`window.sessionStorage.getItem(field)` to read a value
`window.sessionStorage.removeItem(field)` to delete a value
`window.sessionStorage.clear()` to delete everything

or in the same manner

`localStorage.setItem(field, value)`
`localStorage.getItem(field)`
`localStorage.removeItem(field)`
`localStorage.clear()`

The difference between `sessionStorage` and `localStorage` is that sessionStorage is limited to the current browser tab. localStorage is a little more persistent and can be accessed from any tab in the browser and depending on the browser and setting even in a completely new session.

Everything will be saved as a string! If you save a number, an integer for example you will need to parse it again after retrieval ( parseInt() ).

Here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jHWUSFCawZQNBokvxFdA?p=preview) example using sessionStorage.

**Cookies**

Cookies are slightly more involved, on stackoverflow I found a link to this very nice [overview](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html).

Here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wd3nYTBE93DkuYMLtNUy?p=preview) using the very straight forward script provided by the afore mentioned quirksmode website.

`createCookie(field, value, x)`  saves the value to a cookie that is valid for x days
`readCookie(field)`  reads the value from the cookie

Note the the script.js in this plnkr is different from the one in the first plnkr!

Comment: Your source link is in German. I doubt everyone on SO can read German. I know some, but not enough to understand that whole page.

Comment: The link is just for reference. I don't want to make it appear that I am the author of it.

Comment: Am I able to set the GET('troops') to a variable so I can use it later on?

Comment: Sure: `var troops = GET('troops');`. Check out the level5.html in this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XevWu2hXBAx9d5eLD791?p=preview).

Comment: would I then be able to use that variable on the next page? or would i have to set it up all over again because I can't seem to get the var troops to carry over to yet another page e.g level6.html essentially I'm trying to set up a variable I can access on any page.

Comment: In this case you would have to send it again as URL parameter or explore one of the more sophisticated solutions like sessions or cookies. I will add some examples of these to my answer.

Comment: Edited all plunks to have two levels.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies.

```
 <input type="text" id="name">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="button2" value="Submit" onClick="javascript:verify()"/>
```

In the javascript function verify() , you can set a cookie as below

```
 function verify()
 {
   var yourname = document.getElementById('name').value;  
   document.cookie = "name="+yourname;
 }
```

Later you can access it anywhere in your code.

Refer http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_cookies.htm